# Get or Pass Sensitive Data via AJAX in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I want to update a row of data in a database using Ajax and PHP; however, I'm struggling with the following issue: **the field in the database to update (henceforth the `id`) is dependent on the page the ajax request is sent from**.

I need to get this `id` to my PHP script that Ajax calls, however:

1. I don't want to set the `id` in a data attribute or hidden input on the page because these can both be manipulated by a malicious user.
2. Similarly, identifying the `id` using the referring URL is also prone to spoofing as `$_SERVER` isn't secure.
3. I can't set the `id` in a SESSION variable (or COOKIES) because the user could have multiple pages open and the SESSION would only hold the last page `id` that was opened.

The only solution I can think is to create a map of random tokens to `id`'s in a table in the db and pass that in a SESSION variable (as per #3 above), then check the table for the token and grab the respective `id` that way. Seems somewhat convoluted though.

Are there any other options or thoughts? Thanks.

Comment: Generate access tokens for the user and keep them in your session/database as an array?

Comment: ^ i agree.. you can use access tokens..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a problem related to [OWASP Top10 A7](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2013-A7-Missing_Function_Level_Access_Control) (Missing Function Level Access Control).

There might be no issue with putting your ID on the page so the page can send it back - you just **need to validate** that the actual save request is permitted for the user.

Just think, regardless of whether you put the ID on the page or not, the page does know the base url for performing the action, so they could go ahead and guess IDs anyway.

Comment: Validating user authority (which is already done) does not prevent an authorised user from exposing access to other authorised `id`s. This is sound advice, but not quite complete in that (developer-)unintended manipulation is still possible.

Comment: If user authorisation is already done, then you're not preventing anything by adding a complex token solution. The user already has permission to edit any ID. I'm not sure I really understand what you're trying to protect here. Except that they might "mistakenly" edit the source code and then edit the wrong ID.

Comment: No, you're correct in your points. I realised that I'm trying to protect the user from him/herself, which is an arguable gray area of concern for a developer. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Simplify your logic.  Pass some sort of indicator of what type of id is in use from the client to the server.

If you create overly complex application logic to address a security concern you will probably have more problems with your code than improvements in security.

Use SSL/HTTPS and a WAF (web application firewall - like mod_security).